# WSL is doing something resource heavy every 15 minutes

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have some WSL processes running on the system and, every 15th minute of an hour (i.e 00, 15, 30, 45), my system is hanging for a moment, with the freeze time being relative to how many `wslhost.exe` processes are running at that moment.

I've searched through both Task Scheduler and `crontab` and found nothing to cause the issue. Simplest way to avoid this is to kill all `wslhost` processes before time comes to 15th minute, but maybe there are some actual workarounds/fixes?

Comment: Is anything shown in the eventviewer or the WSL logs?

Comment: eventviewer is empty for that moments, `rsyslogd` was not started in linux, I've started it now, and it does not contain anything for 00 mark, will look forward for 15th minute..

Comment: still nothing, it seems that that's something on windows side, some poll actions to background processes maybe

Comment: Don't kill wslhost process. Check the output of `ps` or `top`.